# python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04

I am new in the world of programming, as well as to Ubuntu and Python. I am currently trying to access my setup.py module in the terminal. As of right now, the error it gives me is this:

```
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Honestly, I am not sure how to get this module or where to get this module. I have it on Windows, and it seems to work just fine. I have assumed that since python was already installed on Ubuntu, setup.py would already be here. I think I have assumed wrong.

Any help on this issue would be fantastic. If I need to supply more information, please let me know. :)

Comment: Post your folder structure and the *exact* command you ran. You're probably just in the wrong directory.